# how to create a responsive row of UI cards

Tags: html, css

I am trying create a responsive UI cards out of the card the design below for dynamic content. The current design shrinks the cards and their content instead of rearranging the cards as the screen gets smaller. This is the current cards designs.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap");
/***** CSS VARIABLES *****/
/***** CSS RESET *****/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #15202b;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card {
  height: 250px;
  width: 440px;
  border: 1px solid #38444c;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.card article {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
.card article p {
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

.profile {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.image img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.username {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.username h4 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.username span {
  color: #566471;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.tweet-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3px;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #38444c;
}
.tweet-info span {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #566471;
}

.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png");
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 3000%;
} 

.is_animating {
  animation: heart-burst 0.8s steps(28) 1;
}

@keyframes heart-burst {
  from {
    background-position: left;
  }
  to {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
M
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Twitter Like Animation </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class='card'>
  <div class='profile'>
    <div class='image'>
      <img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1420218664763068416/E5M2zbLg_400x400.jpg' alt='profile image' />
    </div>
    <div class='username'>
      <h4>Ayush</h4>
      <a href='https://twitter.com/ayushgptaa' target='_blank'> <span>@ayushgptaa</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>

    <p>Hey Lovely people, I Created this Twitter card using CSS</p>
  </article>
  <div class='tweet-info'>
    <span>4:20AM ·</span> <span> Jul 26, 2021 · </span><span>Twitter Web App</span>
  </div>
  <div class='icons'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M14.046 2.242l-4.148-.01h-.002c-4.374 0-7.8 3.427-7.8 7.802 0 4.098 3.186 7.206 7.465 7.37v3.828c0 .108.044.286.12.403.142.225.384.347.632.347.138 0 .277-.038.402-.118.264-.168 6.473-4.14 8.088-5.506 1.902-1.61 3.04-3.97 3.043-6.312v-.017c-.006-4.367-3.43-7.787-7.8-7.788zm3.787 12.972c-1.134.96-4.862 3.405-6.772 4.643V16.67c0-.414-.335-.75-.75-.75h-.396c-3.66 0-6.318-2.476-6.318-5.886 0-3.534 2.768-6.302 6.3-6.302l4.147.01h.002c3.532 0 6.3 2.766 6.302 6.296-.003 1.91-.942 3.844-2.514 5.176z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M23.77 15.67c-.292-.293-.767-.293-1.06 0l-2.22 2.22V7.65c0-2.068-1.683-3.75-3.75-3.75h-5.85c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h5.85c1.24 0 2.25 1.01 2.25 2.25v10.24l-2.22-2.22c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0s-.294.768 0 1.06l3.5 3.5c.145.147.337.22.53.22s.383-.072.53-.22l3.5-3.5c.294-.292.294-.767 0-1.06zm-10.66 3.28H7.26c-1.24 0-2.25-1.01-2.25-2.25V6.46l2.22 2.22c.148.147.34.22.532.22s.384-.073.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.768 0-1.06l-3.5-3.5c-.293-.294-.768-.294-1.06 0l-3.5 3.5c-.294.292-.294.767 0 1.06s.767.293 1.06 0l2.22-2.22V16.7c0 2.068 1.683 3.75 3.75 3.75h5.85c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75s-.337-.75-.75-.75z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="heart"></div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M17.53 7.47l-5-5c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0l-5 5c-.294.293-.294.768 0 1.06s.767.294 1.06 0l3.72-3.72V15c0 .414.336.75.75.75s.75-.336.75-.75V4.81l3.72 3.72c.146.147.338.22.53.22s.384-.072.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.767 0-1.06z"></path>
        <path d="M19.708 21.944H4.292C3.028 21.944 2 20.916 2 19.652V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 .437.355.792.792.792h15.416c.437 0 .792-.355.792-.792V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 1.264-1.028 2.292-2.292 2.292z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>
</div>

<br>


<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class='card'>
  <div class='profile'>
    <div class='image'>
      <img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1420218664763068416/E5M2zbLg_400x400.jpg' alt='profile image' />
    </div>
    <div class='username'>
      <h4>Ayush</h4>
      <a href='https://twitter.com/ayushgptaa' target='_blank'> <span>@ayushgptaa</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>

    <p>Hey Lovely people, I Created this Twitter card using CSS</p>
  </article>
  <div class='tweet-info'>
    <span>4:20AM ·</span> <span> Jul 26, 2021 · </span><span>Twitter Web App</span>
  </div>
  <div class='icons'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M14.046 2.242l-4.148-.01h-.002c-4.374 0-7.8 3.427-7.8 7.802 0 4.098 3.186 7.206 7.465 7.37v3.828c0 .108.044.286.12.403.142.225.384.347.632.347.138 0 .277-.038.402-.118.264-.168 6.473-4.14 8.088-5.506 1.902-1.61 3.04-3.97 3.043-6.312v-.017c-.006-4.367-3.43-7.787-7.8-7.788zm3.787 12.972c-1.134.96-4.862 3.405-6.772 4.643V16.67c0-.414-.335-.75-.75-.75h-.396c-3.66 0-6.318-2.476-6.318-5.886 0-3.534 2.768-6.302 6.3-6.302l4.147.01h.002c3.532 0 6.3 2.766 6.302 6.296-.003 1.91-.942 3.844-2.514 5.176z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M23.77 15.67c-.292-.293-.767-.293-1.06 0l-2.22 2.22V7.65c0-2.068-1.683-3.75-3.75-3.75h-5.85c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h5.85c1.24 0 2.25 1.01 2.25 2.25v10.24l-2.22-2.22c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0s-.294.768 0 1.06l3.5 3.5c.145.147.337.22.53.22s.383-.072.53-.22l3.5-3.5c.294-.292.294-.767 0-1.06zm-10.66 3.28H7.26c-1.24 0-2.25-1.01-2.25-2.25V6.46l2.22 2.22c.148.147.34.22.532.22s.384-.073.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.768 0-1.06l-3.5-3.5c-.293-.294-.768-.294-1.06 0l-3.5 3.5c-.294.292-.294.767 0 1.06s.767.293 1.06 0l2.22-2.22V16.7c0 2.068 1.683 3.75 3.75 3.75h5.85c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75s-.337-.75-.75-.75z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="heart"></div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M17.53 7.47l-5-5c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0l-5 5c-.294.293-.294.768 0 1.06s.767.294 1.06 0l3.72-3.72V15c0 .414.336.75.75.75s.75-.336.75-.75V4.81l3.72 3.72c.146.147.338.22.53.22s.384-.072.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.767 0-1.06z"></path>
        <path d="M19.708 21.944H4.292C3.028 21.944 2 20.916 2 19.652V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 .437.355.792.792.792h15.416c.437 0 .792-.355.792-.792V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 1.264-1.028 2.292-2.292 2.292z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like the cards to behave like this [codepen responsive card design](https://codepen.io/codetimeio/full/RYMEJe)

how can i create a responsive row of cards out the card design ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex-wrap: wrap is very important here. The `flex-wrap` property specifies whether the flexible items should wrap or not.
We apply `flex-wrap` to flex the item, so that when the screen size shrinks, overflowed content will be set to a new line. I would recommend you to wrap the card in a card container and apply display flex, instead of applying flex directly to the body.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap");
/***** CSS VARIABLES *****/
/***** CSS RESET *****/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /*to wrap overflowed content*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /*to show vertically overflowed content*/
  background: #15202b;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card {
  height: 250px;
  width: 440px;
  border: 1px solid #38444c;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.card article {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
.card article p {
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

.profile {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.image img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.username {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.username h4 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.username span {
  color: #566471;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.tweet-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3px;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #38444c;
}
.tweet-info span {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #566471;
}

.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png");
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 3000%;
} 

.is_animating {
  animation: heart-burst 0.8s steps(28) 1;
}

@keyframes heart-burst {
  from {
    background-position: left;
  }
  to {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
M
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Twitter Like Animation </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class='card'>
  <div class='profile'>
    <div class='image'>
      <img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1420218664763068416/E5M2zbLg_400x400.jpg' alt='profile image' />
    </div>
    <div class='username'>
      <h4>Ayush</h4>
      <a href='https://twitter.com/ayushgptaa' target='_blank'> <span>@ayushgptaa</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>

    <p>Hey Lovely people, I Created this Twitter card using CSS</p>
  </article>
  <div class='tweet-info'>
    <span>4:20AM ·</span> <span> Jul 26, 2021 · </span><span>Twitter Web App</span>
  </div>
  <div class='icons'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M14.046 2.242l-4.148-.01h-.002c-4.374 0-7.8 3.427-7.8 7.802 0 4.098 3.186 7.206 7.465 7.37v3.828c0 .108.044.286.12.403.142.225.384.347.632.347.138 0 .277-.038.402-.118.264-.168 6.473-4.14 8.088-5.506 1.902-1.61 3.04-3.97 3.043-6.312v-.017c-.006-4.367-3.43-7.787-7.8-7.788zm3.787 12.972c-1.134.96-4.862 3.405-6.772 4.643V16.67c0-.414-.335-.75-.75-.75h-.396c-3.66 0-6.318-2.476-6.318-5.886 0-3.534 2.768-6.302 6.3-6.302l4.147.01h.002c3.532 0 6.3 2.766 6.302 6.296-.003 1.91-.942 3.844-2.514 5.176z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M23.77 15.67c-.292-.293-.767-.293-1.06 0l-2.22 2.22V7.65c0-2.068-1.683-3.75-3.75-3.75h-5.85c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h5.85c1.24 0 2.25 1.01 2.25 2.25v10.24l-2.22-2.22c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0s-.294.768 0 1.06l3.5 3.5c.145.147.337.22.53.22s.383-.072.53-.22l3.5-3.5c.294-.292.294-.767 0-1.06zm-10.66 3.28H7.26c-1.24 0-2.25-1.01-2.25-2.25V6.46l2.22 2.22c.148.147.34.22.532.22s.384-.073.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.768 0-1.06l-3.5-3.5c-.293-.294-.768-.294-1.06 0l-3.5 3.5c-.294.292-.294.767 0 1.06s.767.293 1.06 0l2.22-2.22V16.7c0 2.068 1.683 3.75 3.75 3.75h5.85c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75s-.337-.75-.75-.75z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="heart"></div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M17.53 7.47l-5-5c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0l-5 5c-.294.293-.294.768 0 1.06s.767.294 1.06 0l3.72-3.72V15c0 .414.336.75.75.75s.75-.336.75-.75V4.81l3.72 3.72c.146.147.338.22.53.22s.384-.072.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.767 0-1.06z"></path>
        <path d="M19.708 21.944H4.292C3.028 21.944 2 20.916 2 19.652V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 .437.355.792.792.792h15.416c.437 0 .792-.355.792-.792V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 1.264-1.028 2.292-2.292 2.292z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>
</div>

<br>


<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class='card'>
  <div class='profile'>
    <div class='image'>
      <img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1420218664763068416/E5M2zbLg_400x400.jpg' alt='profile image' />
    </div>
    <div class='username'>
      <h4>Ayush</h4>
      <a href='https://twitter.com/ayushgptaa' target='_blank'> <span>@ayushgptaa</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>

    <p>Hey Lovely people, I Created this Twitter card using CSS</p>
  </article>
  <div class='tweet-info'>
    <span>4:20AM ·</span> <span> Jul 26, 2021 · </span><span>Twitter Web App</span>
  </div>
  <div class='icons'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M14.046 2.242l-4.148-.01h-.002c-4.374 0-7.8 3.427-7.8 7.802 0 4.098 3.186 7.206 7.465 7.37v3.828c0 .108.044.286.12.403.142.225.384.347.632.347.138 0 .277-.038.402-.118.264-.168 6.473-4.14 8.088-5.506 1.902-1.61 3.04-3.97 3.043-6.312v-.017c-.006-4.367-3.43-7.787-7.8-7.788zm3.787 12.972c-1.134.96-4.862 3.405-6.772 4.643V16.67c0-.414-.335-.75-.75-.75h-.396c-3.66 0-6.318-2.476-6.318-5.886 0-3.534 2.768-6.302 6.3-6.302l4.147.01h.002c3.532 0 6.3 2.766 6.302 6.296-.003 1.91-.942 3.844-2.514 5.176z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M23.77 15.67c-.292-.293-.767-.293-1.06 0l-2.22 2.22V7.65c0-2.068-1.683-3.75-3.75-3.75h-5.85c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h5.85c1.24 0 2.25 1.01 2.25 2.25v10.24l-2.22-2.22c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0s-.294.768 0 1.06l3.5 3.5c.145.147.337.22.53.22s.383-.072.53-.22l3.5-3.5c.294-.292.294-.767 0-1.06zm-10.66 3.28H7.26c-1.24 0-2.25-1.01-2.25-2.25V6.46l2.22 2.22c.148.147.34.22.532.22s.384-.073.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.768 0-1.06l-3.5-3.5c-.293-.294-.768-.294-1.06 0l-3.5 3.5c-.294.292-.294.767 0 1.06s.767.293 1.06 0l2.22-2.22V16.7c0 2.068 1.683 3.75 3.75 3.75h5.85c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75s-.337-.75-.75-.75z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="heart"></div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-50lct3 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1srniue">
      <g>
        <path d="M17.53 7.47l-5-5c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0l-5 5c-.294.293-.294.768 0 1.06s.767.294 1.06 0l3.72-3.72V15c0 .414.336.75.75.75s.75-.336.75-.75V4.81l3.72 3.72c.146.147.338.22.53.22s.384-.072.53-.22c.293-.293.293-.767 0-1.06z"></path>
        <path d="M19.708 21.944H4.292C3.028 21.944 2 20.916 2 19.652V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 .437.355.792.792.792h15.416c.437 0 .792-.355.792-.792V14c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75v5.652c0 1.264-1.028 2.292-2.292 2.292z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please not abuse formatting by writing everything in capitals and sticking bold and/or italics in random places, often leaving unmatched asterisks floating about? It makes your posts a lot less readable than they should be. I've edited this one, please take it as an example for future posts and edit your past ones accordingly. You'll get better responses on your posts that way.